# Retiring to Europe from California-Implications for taxes, drivers license & voting

Tags: united-states, taxes, income, california, moving

I retired & moved to Italy April 2018.  I will be living in Europe for at least ten years. In filling out my California state tax form, there was a question regarding whether I moved out of the state. The answer is yes, but I still derive rental income from the two houses that I own in the state. I am concerned that if I answer yes, I may not be able to renew my drivers license in 2020 (I will not be applying for an Italian driving license) or vote in the state elections in 2020.

I have not moved to another state where I can have these benefits.

Can I maintain my driver's license & state voting rights while living outside of the country.

Do I have to pay annual California taxes in order to do so?

Thank you for your responses to my questions.

Comment: Hi MangoRox. Thanks for contributing here. We have another site called [Expatriates](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com) which deals with moving abroad generally. Your non-finance questions might be better asked there.

Comment: Are you expecting to spend most of your time in Europe after you retire?

Comment: You really should get an EU drivers license asap, while certain foreign ones are valid in the EU, they are only usable by visitors staying for a short time. If you want to drive in the EU long term you will need a license there.